# Implementing operator< in C++

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class with a few numeric fields such as:

```
class Class1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    // constructor and so on...
    bool operator<(const Class1& other) const;
};
```

I need to use objects of this class as a key in an `std::map`. I therefore implement `operator<`. What is the simplest implementation of `operator<` to use here?

**EDIT:**
The meaning of `<` can be assumed so as to guarantee uniqueness as long as any of the fields are unequal.

**EDIT 2:**

A simplistic implementation:

```
bool Class1::operator<(const Class1& other) const {
    if(a < other.a) return true;
    if(a > other.a) return false;

    if(b < other.b) return true;
    if(b > other.b) return false;

    if(c < other.c) return true;
    if(c > other.c) return false;

    return false;
}
```

The whole reason behind this post is just that I found the above implementation too verbose. There ought to be something simpler.

Comment: You must first decide what '<' means for the case where multiple members represent the invariant of the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on if the ordering is important to you in any way.  If not, you could just do this:

```
bool operator<(const Class1& other) const
{
    if(a == other.a)
    {
         if(b == other.b)
         {
             return c < other.c;
         }
         else
         {
             return b < other.b;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        return a < other.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, for fun, `return a!=other.a?a<other.a:b!=other.b?b<other.b:c<other.c;`

Comment: I don't see in what way this is better than the "simplistic implementation" that the OP gave. This version is less readable.

Answer (score 40):

I assume you want to implement lexicographical ordering.

Prior to C++11:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>
bool Class1::operator<(const Class1& other) const
{
    return boost::tie(a, b, c) < boost::tie(other.a, other.b, other.c);
}
```

Since C++11:

```
#include <tuple>
bool Class1::operator<(const Class1& other) const
{
    return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(other.a, other.b, other.c);
}
```

Comment: Nice! But boost is too heavy for my particular case.

Comment: Great, never thought of using tuples!

Comment: @Agnel Kurian: no need to 'use' it further than this one tie. It is header-only too, to minimize build impact (time/dependencies) you can isolate it into a separate compilation unit (but for release builds, consider doing it in the header for inlining!)

Comment: With a recent compiler you can use std::tie after including <tuple> header :)

Answer (score 15):

I think there is a misunderstanding on what `map` requires.

`map` does not require your class to have `operator<` defined. It requires a suitable comparison predicate to be passed, which conveniently defaults to `std::less<Key>` which uses `operator<` on the `Key`.

You should not implement `operator<` to fit your key in the `map`. You should implement it only if you to define it for this class: ie if it's meaningful.

You could perfectly define a predicate:

```
struct Compare: std::binary_function<Key,Key,bool>
{
  bool operator()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const { ... }
};
```

And then:

```
typedef std::map<Key,Value,Compare> my_map_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A version which avoids multiple indentation is

```
bool operator<(const Class1& other) const
{
    if(a != other.a)
    {
        return a < other.a;
    }

    if(b != other.b)
    {
        return b < other.b;
    }

    return c < other.c;
}
```

The "Edit 2" version of the author has on average more comparisons than this solution. (worst case 6 to worst case 3)

Answer (score -4):

You could do:

```
return memcmp (this, &other, sizeof *this) < 0;
```

but that has quite a lot of of caveats - no vtbl for example and plenty more I'm sure.

Comment: @Peter: The OP only wants `to guarantee uniqueness as long as any of the fields are unequal`, so, adding an offsetof to get the address of the first key field and ensuring the key fields are contiguous, memcmp should do the trick.