# OpenCV, C++: Inserting into set

Tags: c++, list, opencv, netbeans-6.9, ubuntu-11.04

I am developing a C++ application using NetBeans 6.9 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I am using OpenCV  2.3.1.  I was wondering if someone could tell me what is wrong with this code.

`void AddTriangle(CvPoint buf[3], set< Triangle > &V)

{

    Triangle    triangle;

    int         inc;`

```
for (inc=0; inc<3; ++inc)
{
    triangle.v[inc].x=buf[inc].x;
    triangle.v[inc].y=buf[inc].y;
}
V.insert((const Triangle) triangle);
```

}

I get the following error message when I try to compile.

`from /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/locale_classes.h:42,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ios_base.h:43,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/ios:43,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/istream:40,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/sstream:39,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.5/complex:47,

                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:59,

                 from ../../OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv/cv.h:64,

                 from ../../OpenCV-2.3.1/include/opencv/cv.hpp:50,

                 from ../../DraculaFiles/TwoDTriangulation.cpp:12:

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = sTriangle]’:

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/string:50:0,
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_tree.h:1184:4:   instantiated from ‘std::pair, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = sTriangle, _Val = sTriangle, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator]’

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_set.h:408:29:   instantiated from ‘std::pair, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = sTriangle, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator, typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, value_type = sTriangle]’`

Triangle is defined as follows.

typedef struct sTriangle
{
        CvPoint v[3];
} Triangle;

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Peter.

Comment: I have a feeling that is not the full error output. There should be a line which has the word `error` in it.

Comment: While you're retrieving the rest of the error output, is there a reason not to scope your loop counter locally by for(int inc = 0; ...)?

Comment: The rest of the error message is

Comment: The rest of the error message is:/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_function.h:230:22: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
../../DraculaFiles/TwoDTriangulation.cpp:3838:6: note: candidate is: bool operator<(const TriangleInID&, const TriangleInID&)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put `Triangle` into a set, you have to implement comparison operator. Otherwise the set cannot tell which values are equal and which are different.

```
typedef struct sTriangle
{
CvPoint v[3];
bool operator<(const sTriangle& other) const;
} Triangle;

bool sTriangle::operator<(const sTriangle& other) const
{
   // compare 'this' with 'other'
}
```

For the implementation of less operator, you can inspire [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006413/implementing-operator-in-c).

**Edit**: you can implement the less operator even without modifying `sTriangle` structure:

```
typedef struct sCvPoint {
int x;
int y;
} CvPoint;

typedef struct sTriangle
{
CvPoint v[3];
} Triangle;

bool operator==(CvPoint const& left, CvPoint const& right)
{
    return left.x == right.x && left.y == right.y;
}

bool operator<(CvPoint const& left, CvPoint const& right)
{
    return left.x == right.x
        ? left.y < right.y
        : left.x < right.x;
}

bool operator<(Triangle const& left, Triangle const& right)
{
    return left.v[0] == right.v[0]
        ? left.v[1] == right.v[1]
            ? left.v[2] < right.v[2]
            : left.v[1] < right.v[1]
        : left.v[0] < right.v[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

STL fails to distinguish instances of triangles in a set and it was looking for overloaded  "<" operator.