# std::set error: no match for »operator<«

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I have a class (extract):

```
class Package
{
private:
        string s_package_name;
        float f_boottime;
        float f_bytesize;
        list <Package> l_depends;
        list <Package> l_selects;
}
```

I'd like to generate many objects and list them in a unique "array", therefore i took `set` I add the objects like this:

```
set<Package> l_tempSet;   
Package PackageA(1, 11, "what a package");
Package PackageB(2, 22, "what a 2nd package");

l_tempSet.insert(PackageA);
l_tempSet.insert(PackageB);
```

When compiling I receive an error Message:

> no match for »operator<« (operand types are »const Package« and »const
>   Package«)

When clicking into the Error Message it points me to the set.h to the line where `unique` is called and I think this is the error.

Is it true that C++ isn't capable to "unique" objects (like in this example) into lists and sets and can just handle easy data types like int, float etc. ? Or did I went wrong somewhere, please help me I'm not sure where the error is exactly.

Thanks for your suppport

Comment: Implement the operator< for your class

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. (Do you have any search-tags to google arround?)

Comment: I have added a reference for each solution in my answer.

Comment: If yor question is answered, you should make sure to mark an answer as accepted, for future reference.

Comment: I suspect you don't want to add _copies_ of the objects as you are trying to. Remember, C++ has _value_ semantics for everything.

Comment: Is it possible to give me some search-tags to google around, about the "<operator" and/or the "class comperator" ? Don't get me wrong but none of both solution are actually explained

Comment: There are links in my answer, just click on them and read the references. Also the question that is marked as original has answers with references.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that a c++ [`std::set` is orderd](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), therefore it needs to sort the elements by evaluating the `operator<`.

Basically there are three solutions to your problem:

1. Implement the `operator<` for your class (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006413/implementing-operator-in-c))

   ```
    bool operator<(const Package& other) const
    {
        //return true if this < other
    }
   ```
2. Use an unsorted set like [`std::unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), but then you'll have to implement the equality operator and a hash function.
3. Implement a comparator function and pass it to the `set` as second template parameter:

   ```
    bool smaller (const Package& left, const Package& right) 
    {
        //return true if left < right;
    }
    std::set<Package,std::function<bool(const Package&, const Package&)>> newSet (std::function<bool(const Package&, const Package&)>(smaller));
   ```

Comment: If you go with an `unordered_set`, you then have 2 problems.  You have to implement a hash function, and an equality operator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that is true, I added it in the answer. But it does still solve the operator < problem ;)

Comment: It doesn't have to evaluate `operator<`. You can instantiate a set with your own comparison logic (in the form of a user defined functor). This is a good strategy to use if there is no natural `operator<` for your class.

Comment: @juanchopanza sounds like a good idea with an own compare-value. But I guess this doesn't solve the "unique" problem.

Comment: @user3085931 It does.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right, I edited.

Comment: I tried (3): function and newSet couldn't be resolved, am I a special kind of header missing? I got iostream,string,list and set.

Comment: @user3085931 you need the header `<functional>` for function. newSet ist just a variable of type std::set.
Try to google it yourself, I am really not here to search header files for you.

Comment: Option 1. code needs to be corrected. Operator itself must be const.
bool operator<(const Package& other) const {
    //return true if this < other
}

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `operator<` for your class. Otherwise, `set` cannot compare objects it's supposed to store, thus cannot check their uniqueness.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that addresses the question of what uniqueness actually means.

Comment: @KerrekSB with the caveat that you don't *have* to define `operator<`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah... it would be best to start logically with "what does it mean to be unique", and develop possible solutions from there. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `std::set`, internal implementation may use `operator <` to arrange objects into buckets, RBTree etc.(Because `std::set` is ordered) So it needs `operator <`. Compiler doesn't provide comparision operator by default, so you need to implement 1 by yourself.

```
class Package
{
private:
        string s_package_name;
        float f_boottime;
        float f_bytesize;
        list <Package> l_depends;
        list <Package> l_selects;
public:
        bool operator <(const Package &t) {
          /* your logic */
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for (all!) of your quick responses. I googled a bit around I couldn't find anything. I think I understood the logic behind it but I'm not quiet sure about the implementation: what is exactly in the body of the bool operator and what's the "&t"

Comment: `&t` means t is a [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm). About body, you can put any logic that can tell whether 1 object is less than other or not.

Comment: Don't blame the compiler. It's just doing what it's told. The language does not allow it to invent operator overloads.